# Opera 11 tab bar below address bar

Tags: opera, opera-11

In Opera 11, is it possible to have the tab bar below the address bar?

I'm running Opera 11.61 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, (and thats why I started to hate every new browser...) and [this solution (from nontroppo.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140415152912/http://nontroppo.org/-/media/mainbar.htm) worked for me:

In a nutshell:

- Right click on any bar -> Customize -> Appearance
- In the window, turn on "Main Bar"
- Delete all the buttons from it and drag all the stuff from the
  address bar to here. (note: they will be duplicates, don't worry.)
- Disable the useless "Address Bar" by unchecking it.
- Live happily forever! (or until some "interface designer" ruin your favorite program again...)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
1. Go to O Menu > Appearance > Toolbars
2. Check ☑Show hidden toolbars while customizing
3. Click old Personal bar and select Placement different than Off
4. Turn off (⌧uncheck) the Bookmarks bar
```

I don't have Opera so I can't run through it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tamil's blog post](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/tab-bar-below-address-bar) about this to see how to do it. You may have to read through some of the comments to see how to apply this to Opera 11 as the instructions were written a long time ago and many menu paths have changed. There are also some caveats with extensions not showing up by default, I believe.

Having said that, why on earth would you want to change the ordering? It makes much more sense to have separate address bars for each tab, you can even start typing something in one tab, check something on another tab, come back to the first and continue typing. Even Firefox has recognised that this way makes more sense and has changed the ordering to be the same as Opera. Chrome also uses this order. But, being Opera, you can customise the UI pretty much however you want...